# Nearly any Microsoft services that uses http requests isn't working

Tags: windows-10, login, http

I bought a new notebook which comes with pre-installed windows 10 version. Right on installation, when asked to enter my Microsoft account it didn't work. So I rather used a local account, as suggested by the application. But when I went to use the Windows, pretty much anything related to MS wasn't working. I tried sign-in OpenDrive, resulted in error. Windows Store isn't downloading anything. The downloads stuck at 0% without error messages. Skype app doesn't work at all, right when I hit enter after typed my password, it back automatically to the login screen. I guess no http request is done at all. My guess is there's something blocking the http requests from this services/apps, my I don't what or when look up for it. How do I fix this?

Comment: This sounds like an ISP related issue.  Have you tried switching to a different DNS?

Comment: So what about a browser, can you surf the web? Can you login to Microsoft services?

Comment: @Ramhound: I changed to google DNS and it worked fine! Thanks!

Comment: @DanielB: Web browsing is fine, I posted from the very same computer with the issue (now fixed, thanks to Ramhound)

Comment: Great that you got the problem solved.  Please consider posting an answer that describes exactly what you did.  That will help other users with a similar problem.

Answer (score 1):

Hope it's useful to anyone, as suggested by [`@ramhound`](https://superuser.com/users/83283/ramhound) I changed my DNS to [`OpenDNS`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenDNS) and everything is working fine.